# Create a tag searching bar

Tags: java, html, json, search, searchbar

I'm a beginner in web-programming and I've got this problem with a search bar. The thing is how do I finish it so it'd give out a drop bar with prospective results to choose from and to select other div to give out the search results themselves? Should be something similar as the tag search bar down this page.

The code is below and thanks in advance! WHERE "TODO"!!!

```
<head>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var delay = (function(){ // to set timer
            var timer = 0;
            return function(callback, ms){
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
            };
        })();

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var $search = $("#search");
            $search.keyup(function() {
                delay(function () {
                    var $string = $("#search").val();
                    if ( $string == "" || /\s+$/.test($string)) return;
                    var $tag = $string.match(/\S+$/)[0]
                    $.getJSON('/get_tags_by_substring', {'tag':$tag}, function ($data) {
                        console.log($data);
                        /* TODO */   
                    });
                }, 500);
            });
        });   </script> </head>

<style>
    .search_bar{
        bottom: 5px;
        right: 100px;
        /* margin-right: 10px; */
        float: right;
    } </style>

<header> <style type="text/css"> .form {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px; } </style>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id = "header" style="display: table; width: 1150px;">
            <div id="logo" style="display: table-cell;">
                <a href="/">
                   {% load staticfiles %}
                   <!--img src="{% static '.../images/logo_1.png'%}" alt="... logo" align="left"-->
                </a>
            </div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;">
                <nav id="navig" style="margin:0px;">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="button"><a href="/fiction/">1</a></li>
                        <li class="button"><a href="/people/">2</a></li>
                        <li class="button"><a href="/gastro/">3</a></li>
                        <li class="button"><a href="/">4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="search_bar">
                <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="tag..."/><br/>
                <div id="search_results"></div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div> </header>
```